# Where is the hidden camera api?

Tags: android, camera

I look for a way to control the shutter/exposure time for the camera. Unfortunately this is not possible with the public API.

I found the Android [Camera App FV-5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.pro&hl=de) which exactly does this and it really works on the Galaxy S3.

So my question is: How to do the impossible? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such Hidden API, at least in android. At most, android can list what abilities camera has and you can pass such parameters to take picture. These parameters will differ from device to device. The App you mentioned just grabs many continuous frames and adds them up by code (stacking). Read their FAQ's: http://www.camerafv5.com/faq.php#long-exposure-resolution .